# Close socket before device goes in doze mode

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm working on a chat app with tcp socket and getting some issues when device goes in doze mode (Android M & N). As we all know that doze reduces battery consumption by deferring background CPU and network activity for apps when the device is unused for long periods of time. so before device goes in doze mode i want to tell server that device is now going to doze mode and now need to send messages to devices through push notification(gcm/fcm).

If anyone have solution please write here.

Answer (score 1):

Register for the broadcast `Intent` `PowerManager.ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGE`. That `Intent` will be sent when the device goes in and out of doze mode.

Comment: after device goes in idle mode is network connection will alive ?

Comment: That's a good point...no, it probably will not be.  So having the client "tell" the backend that it is in a doze mode and should switch to FCM is likely going to be problematic.